# word2vec window size at sentence boundaries

Tags: gensim, word2vec

I am using word2vec (and doc2vec) to get embeddings for sentences, but i want to completely ignore word order.
I am currently using gensim, but can use other packages if necessary.

As an example, my text looks like this:

```
[
['apple', 'banana','carrot','dates', 'elderberry', ..., 'zucchini'],
['aluminium', 'brass','copper', ..., 'zinc'],
...
]
```

I intentionally want 'apple' to be considered as close to 'zucchini' as it is to 'banana' so I have set the window size to a very large number, say 1000.
I am aware of 2 problems that may arise with this.

Problem 1:
The window might *roll* in at the start of a sentence creating the following training pairs:
`('apple', ('banana')), ('apple', ('banana', 'carrot')), ('apple', ('banana', 'carrot', 'date'))` before it eventually gets to the correct `('apple', ('banana','carrot', ..., 'zucchini'))`.
This would seem to have the effect of making 'apple' closer to 'banana' than 'zucchini',
since their are so many more pairs containing 'apple' and 'banana' than there are pairs containing 'apple' and 'zucchini'.

Problem 2:
I heard that pairs are sampled with inverse proportion to the distance from the target word to the context word- This also causes an issue making nearby words more seem more connected than I want them to be.

Is there a way around problems 1 and 2?
Should I be using cbow as opposed to sgns? Are there any other hyperparameters that I should be aware of?
What is the best way to go about removing/ignoring the order in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "Problem 1" - there's no "roll" or "wraparound" in the usual interpretation of a word2vec-style algorithm's `window` parameter. So I wouldn't worry about this.

Regarding "Problem 2", this factor can be essentially made negligible by the choice of a giant `window` value – say for example, a value one million times larger than your largest sentence. Then, any difference in how the algorithm treats the nearest-word and the 2nd-nearest-word is vanishingly tiny.

(More specifically, the way the gensim implementation – which copies the original Google `word2vec.c` in this respect – achieves a sort of distance-based weighting is actually via random dynamic shrinking of the actual `window` used. That is, for each visit during training to each target word, the effective `window` truly used is some random number from 1 to the user-specified `window`. By effectively using smaller windows much of the time, the nearer words have more influence – just without the cost of performing other scaling on the whole window's words every time. But in your case, with a giant `window` value, it will be incredibly rare for the effective-window to ever be smaller than your actual sentences. Thus every word will be included, equally, almost every time.)

All these considerations would be the same using SG or CBOW mode.

I believe a million-times-larger `window` will be adequate for your needs, for if for some reason it wasn't, another way to essentially cancel-out any nearness effects could be to ensure your corpus's items individual word-orders are re-shuffled between each time they're accessed as training data. That ensures any nearness advantages will be mixed evenly across all words – especially if each sentence is trained on many times. (In a large-enough corpus, perhaps even just a 1-time shuffle of each sentence would be enough. Then, over all examples of co-occurring words, the word co-occurrences would be sampled in the right proportions even with small windows.)

Other tips:

If your training data starts in some arranged order that clumps words/topics together, it can be beneficial to shuffle them into a random order instead. (It's better if the full variety of the data is interleaved, rather than presented in runs of many similar examples.)

When your data isn't true natural-language data (with its usual distributions & ordering significance), it may be worth it to search further from the usual defaults to find optimal metaparameters. This goes for `negative`, `sample`, & especially `ns_exponent`. (One paper has suggested the optimal `ns_exponent` for training vectors for recommendation-systems is far different from the usual 0.75 default for natural-language modeling.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks very much!